# Laravel eager loading with conditional select not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I am trying to select sum of my column value with eager loading.

My query is

```
$transactions = Service::with(['transactions' => function($query) use ($queryData){
        $query->whereIn('status',['Success','Pending','Successful','Processing']);
        $query->whereDate('created_at','>=', $queryData);
        $query->addSelect(DB::raw("SUM(deducted) as adjustment"));
}]);
```

But I am not getting any sum with my response.

my resulted response look like

```
"id": "3",
"name": "Service Name",
"transactions": [ ]
```

But It should be

```
"id": "3",
"name": "Service Name",
"adjustment": 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `withCount()`:

```
$transactions = Service::withCount(['transactions as adjustment' => function($query) use ($queryData){
    $query->whereIn('status',['Success','Pending','Successful','Processing']);
    $query->whereDate('created_at','>=', $queryData);
    $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(deducted)'));
}]);
```

Comment: Small note that this will have `$transaction->adjustment_count` instead of just `$transaction->adjustment`

Comment: @MihirBhende Only in old versions of Laravel.

Comment: Not really :)  [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Comment: @MihirBhende `_count` is only appended when you *don't* use an alias. Try it.

Comment: ohh my bad! Missed that you had an alias

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use the sum function on the collection rather than the raw SQL inside the query. Still only hit the DB once:

I don't know where the deducted sits, but if on the model (which it looks like from the above query) this will give you a sum of those transactions queried:

```
$adjustment= $transactions->sum('deducted');
```

or if on a relation

```
$adjustment= $transactions->sum(function ($transaction) {
    return $transaction->transaction?->sum('deducted');
});
```

You can also possibly get the related field with dot notation as well:

```
$adjustment= $transactions->sum('transaction.deducted');
```

These allow you to keep your object collection (`$transactions`, and the `name` and `id` fields as you noted necessary) and still get the sum from the original query.